# Python Tkinter permutations

Tags: python, tkinter, permutation

I am using Tkinter and have a box with 4 fields. Each field will be entered with a couple words, and I am looking to get all of the possible permuations for the words typed into the 4 fields.

When I run this, it outputs permutations of the different words themselves, not the different possible order of words. How do I get my exact match function to output this? Any help is appreciated.

```
from itertools import permutations
from tkinter import *
fields = 'Campaign', 'Add_Group', 'Location', 'Aux_Groups'


def exact_match(entries):
  for entry in entries:
     field = entry[0]
     text  = entry[1].get()
     perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(text)]
     print (perms)

def makeform(root, fields):
   entries = []
   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=20, text=field, anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=10, pady=10)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries.append((field, ent))
   return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
     root = Tk()
     ents = makeform(root, fields)
     root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))
     b1 = Button(root, text='Show',
            command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
     b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)
     b2 = Button(root, text='Exact Match', command=(lambda e=ents: 
exact_match(e)))

     b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)
     b3 = Button(root, text='Phrase Match', command=root.quit)
     b3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)
     b4 = Button(root, text='Broad Match', command=root.quit)
     b4.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)
     b5 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
     b5.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)
     root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you are running permutations on each letter of entries and not the whole words. Simply gather all entered words together with a list comprehension, then run permutations:

```
def exact_match(entries):
  words = [entry[1].get() for entry in entries]
  perms = [p for p in permutations(words)]
  print(perms)
```